# Why does sqlite store a different value when running through valgrind?

Tags: c++, sqlite, valgrind

In an application I'm writing I notice that when I try to insert a double into an sqlite database, a (slightly) different value is actually stored, but only when the application is running through valgrind. When calling the program directly (without recompiling) all doubles are stored as intended.

This code reproduces the problem. Some safety check and such are removed for brevity.

```cpp
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

class SqliteDB
{
  sqlite3 *d_db;
  bool d_ok;
 public:
  inline SqliteDB(std::string const &name);
  inline ~SqliteDB();
  inline void exec(std::string const &q, std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::any>>> *results);
};

inline SqliteDB::SqliteDB(std::string const &name)
  :
  d_db(nullptr),
  d_ok(false)
{
  d_ok = (sqlite3_open(name.c_str(), &d_db) == 0);
}

inline SqliteDB::~SqliteDB()
{
  if (d_ok)
    sqlite3_close(d_db);
}

inline void SqliteDB::exec(std::string const &q, std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::any>>> *results)
{
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(d_db, q.c_str(), -1, &stmt, nullptr) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    std::cout << "SQL Error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(d_db) << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  int rc;
  results->clear();
  while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
  {
    results->resize(results->size() + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(stmt); ++i)
    {
      if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i) == SQLITE_INTEGER)
      {
        results->back().emplace_back(std::make_pair(sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i), sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, i)));
      }
      else if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i) == SQLITE_FLOAT)
      {
        results->back().emplace_back(std::make_pair(sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i), sqlite3_column_double(stmt, i)));
      }
      else if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i) == SQLITE_TEXT)
      {
        results->back().emplace_back(std::make_pair(sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i), std::string(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i)))));
      }
      else if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i) == SQLITE_BLOB)
      {
        size_t blobsize = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, i);
        std::shared_ptr<unsigned char []> blob(new unsigned char[blobsize]);
        std::memcpy(blob.get(), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, i)), blobsize);
        results->back().emplace_back(std::make_pair(sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i), std::make_pair(blob, blobsize)));
      }
      else if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i) == SQLITE_NULL)
      {
        results->back().emplace_back(std::make_pair(sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i), nullptr));
      }
    }
  }
  if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    std::cout << "SQL Error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(d_db) << std::endl;
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

inline std::string toHexString(double d)
{
  unsigned char *data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&d);
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "(hex:) ";
  for (uint i = 0; i < sizeof(d); ++i)
    oss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
        << (static_cast<int32_t>(data[i]) & 0xFF)
        << ((i == sizeof(d) - 1) ? "" : " ");
  return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
  SqliteDB db(":memory:");
  std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::any>>> results;

  db.exec("CREATE TABLE part (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ratio REAL)", &results);

  double d = 1.4814814329147339;
  std::cout << "Inserting into table: " << std::defaultfloat << std::setprecision(17) << d
            << " " << toHexString(d) << std::endl;

  db.exec("INSERT INTO part VALUES (1,1.4814814329147339)", &results);
  db.exec("SELECT ratio FROM part WHERE _id = 1", &results);
  for (uint i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i)
    for (uint j = 0; j < results[i].size(); ++j)
    {
      if (results[i][j].second.type() == typeid(double))
        std::cout << "Retrieved from table: " << std::defaultfloat << std::setprecision(17) << std::any_cast<double>(results[i][j].second)
                  << " " << toHexString(std::any_cast<double>(results[i][j].second)) << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I have verified that the problem happens when storing the value, not when retrieving it (that is, the database actually contains the differing double). Output of above program:

```sh
[~/valgrindsqlitedouble] $ g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -O1 -g -lsqlite3 main.cc
[~/valgrindsqlitedouble] $ ./a.out 
Inserting into table: 1.4814814329147339 (hex:) 00 00 00 e0 25 b4 f7 3f
Retrieved from table: 1.4814814329147339 (hex:) 00 00 00 e0 25 b4 f7 3f
[~/valgrindsqlitedouble] $ valgrind ./a.out 
==3340== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3340== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3340== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3340== Command: ./a.out
==3340== 
Inserting into table: 1.4814814329147339 (hex:) 00 00 00 e0 25 b4 f7 3f
Retrieved from table: 1.4814814329147341 (hex:) 01 00 00 e0 25 b4 f7 3f
==3340== 
==3340== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3340==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3340==   total heap usage: 299 allocs, 299 frees, 269,972 bytes allocated
==3340== 
==3340== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3340== 
==3340== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3340== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[~/valgrindsqlitedouble] $
```

I assume there is some rounding error happening when sqlite converts the string to double, but can anyone explain why it only happens when valgrind is running?

Second, can I get rid of this problem? In the final program, the precision will not even be that important, but during development it would be good to have predictable output. I'm working with some big binary files and in testing the easiest way to verify the program is working correctly is to compare the generated outputfile (which includes the database) to a known good one. Is there any way I can get sqlite to just insert the 8 bytes I want it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/cmt-40/Nice/RuleRefinement/bin/valgrind-3.2.0/docs/html/manual-core.html):

> Your program is then run on a synthetic CPU provided by the Valgrind core.

So on paper there is plenty of scope for your program's behaviour to vary when run under Valgrind. Of course, in practice we'd hope for this not to be the case, because not only should our programs be portable, but if Valgrind alters their behaviour then it's not really testing what we wanted it to test even on the same platform.

However, your expectation is already non-portable, and the devs use this as a defence in their *Limitations* section:

> As of version 3.0.0, Valgrind has the following limitations in its implementation of x86/AMD64 floating point relative to IEEE754.
>
> Precision: **There is no support for 80 bit arithmetic. Internally, Valgrind represents all such "long double" numbers in 64 bits, and so there may be some differences in results.** Whether or not this is critical remains to be seen. Note, the x86/amd64 fldt/fstpt instructions (read/write 80-bit numbers) are correctly simulated, using conversions to/from 64 bits, so that in-memory images of 80-bit numbers look correct if anyone wants to see.
>
> **The impression observed from many FP regression tests is that the accuracy differences aren't significant. Generally speaking, if a program relies on 80-bit precision, there may be difficulties porting it to non x86/amd64 platforms which only support 64-bit FP precision.** Even on x86/amd64, the program may get different results depending on whether it is compiled to use SSE2 instructions (64-bits only), or x87 instructions (80-bit). **The net effect is to make FP programs behave as if they had been run on a machine with 64-bit IEEE floats, for example PowerPC.** On amd64 FP arithmetic is done by default on SSE2, so amd64 looks more like PowerPC than x86 from an FP perspective, and there are far fewer noticable accuracy differences than with x86.

and

> As of version 3.0.0, Valgrind has the following limitations in its implementation of x86/AMD64 SSE2 FP arithmetic, relative to IEEE754.
>
> Essentially the same: no exceptions, and limited observance of rounding mode. Also, SSE2 has control bits which make it treat denormalised numbers as zero (DAZ) and a related action, flush denormals to zero (FTZ). **Both of these cause SSE2 arithmetic to be less accurate than IEEE requires.** Valgrind detects, ignores, and can warn about, attempts to enable either mode.

*et al.*

I recommend using Valgrind for finding low-level bugs (memory leaks and the like), not for performing any functional testing.

Alternatively, if you have eight specific bytes you want to put into a database, simply do that, rather than going through a floating-point roundtrip.